# Angular Firebase Get Data Sync

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get balance data from firebase. But it must be real-time. 
I write the code below. The console output is "Balance: 0". After this output, it gets firebase data and writes it. So, before data come from firebase, the code continues and get balance function returns 0. I can't compare balance because of that. Actual data comes after that.

```
checkBalance() {
    let balance = this.authService.getBalance()
    result = this.authService.getBalance() >= this.price ? true : false
    console.log("Balance: " + balance);
    return result;
}
```

AuthService:

```
getBalance() {
    
    let docRef = this.angularFirestore.collection(`users`).doc(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')).uid);
    docRef.get().toPromise().then(function (doc) {
        if (doc.exists) {
            console.log(doc.data());
            console.log(doc.data().balance);
            return parseFloat(doc.data().balance);
        } else {
            // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
            console.log("Doc can not find!");
            return 0.0;
        }
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Error getting document:", error);
        return 0.0;
    });
    
    return 0.0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Original Answer

### Steps

1. Mark `getBalance` method `async`, and make it `return` your Promise
2. Mark `checkBalance` method `async`
3. Change the first line as follows: `let balance = await this.authService.getBalance()`

### Sample

```js
async getBalance() {
    const docRef = this.angularFirestore.collection(`users`).doc(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')).uid);

    return docRef.get().toPromise().then(function (doc) {
        if (doc.exists) {
            console.log(doc.data());
            console.log(doc.data().balance);
            return parseFloat(doc.data().balance);
        } else {
            // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
            console.log("Doc can not find!");
            return 0.0;
        }
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Error getting document:", error);
        return 0.0;
    });
}
```

```js
async checkBalance() {
    const balance = await this.authService.getBalance();
    const result = balance >= this.price ? true : false;
    console.log("Balance: " + balance);

    return result;
}
```

### JS Reference

- https://javascript.info/async-await

## Update For Angular 12 or Greater

### Deprecation of toPromise in rxjs 7

Now instead of toPromise you have to use  `lastValueFrom` or `firstValueFrom`  from rxjs

```js
import { firstValueFrom} from "rxjs";
async getBalance() {
    const docRef = this.angularFirestore.collection(`users`).doc(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')).uid);

    return firstValueFrom(docRef.get()).then(function (doc) {
        if (doc.exists) {
            console.log(doc.data());
            console.log(doc.data().balance);
            return parseFloat(doc.data().balance);
        } else {
            // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
            console.log("Doc can not find!");
            return 0.0;
        }
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Error getting document:", error);
        return 0.0;
    });
}
```

### Rxjs Reference

- https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/to-promise

Comment: It works, thank you. I think this is because of the location of await.